# iframe contentWindow weird behaviour (with react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, iframe

Bumped in some kind of an anomaly right now and could not solve this problem today. I am using React with create-react-app locally and testing in Chrome(Firefox same thing). I have an iframe nested deep in a component and trying to set height after onLoad happens.

I can get the iframe no problem,

`console.log( iframe.contentWindow )`

and I can see the whole object, can search for
 document -> body -> scrollHeight. (1044px)

However If I try to access deeper I get empty html. For example

```
console.log( iframe.contentWindow.document )
```

would give me

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It' just and empty html. If I try to query for scrollHeight, I get 150px, thats the visible part of iframe on the viewport.

I just don't get it how logging the contentWindow gives me the whole object, but if I log further towards document it's empty html..

Edit: also loading iframe source with srcdoc attribute using html in a string if that helps.

Edit2: if i query the document of the iframe from the Chrome console I get the full body, only not from code it seems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what browser. Sorry, this shouldn't be tagged as an answer (yet), but I am too new to comment.

Please see an example of how I target an iFrame in some code for work that I needed to be cross platform:

`ifrm = document.getElementById('scriptContainer');`

`ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;`

Then try:

`console.log(ifrm)`, you'll see something like this:

[image: first console ouput]

Not exactly what you want right?

However, not to worry, since your `ifrm` variable now contains the documents window object, we can simply:

`console.log(ifrm.document)`

Which should return something like:

[image]

Hope that's helpful, let me know a bit more about your specific case and I may be able to help further.

Edit: One other thing to consider, is making sure when you run the code to traverse the iframe, it has been fully loaded.

Comment: At the step where you log ifrm.document I get empty html. Now I'm guessing it is because the iframe is not fully loaded and I could only see the iframe object because Chrome console evaluated it later. But if I use the 'onLoad' callback on the iframe , shouldn't it be loaded??

Comment: The iframes "Window" object loads instantly when it is crawled by the htmlDOM parser, it is later populated with more data once it is actually loading the elements inside it which manipulate it. I too think it is because your frames data is not loaded yet, so just anchor the part you need to execute afterward on something like `myIframe.onload(function(){ // your logic })`

Comment: Well it is React and I bound my function the the onLoad event of the iframe, thats why I don't understand why its not loaded.

Comment: Try anchoring it on something that loads inside the document body of the iframe maybe?  Or possibly for just knowledge purpose, set a fairly long delay before you try logging it from the code and we can rule out if it's execution order issue.